# How do i get laravel to set a row in a database to a specific value at midnight?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table in a mysql database and i want to every midnight set a row in that table to false.

How would i go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Create a controller function and execute it at midnight.
Lets say you have `ScheduleController`

```
class ScheduleController extends Controller {
  public function resetDataBase()
  {
    //write query here to change the table row.
    //You may use raw queries
  }
}
```

Then call this function in `App\Console\Kernel.php`

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
  $schedule->call('\App\Http\Controllers\ScheduleController@resetDataBase')
    ->dailyAt('00:00');
}
```

On the server where you have hosted the application, you have to setup a `crontab` entry

```
* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Refer [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/scheduling) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a task to run at midnight and do whatever you want to do in that task. Check out the docs for task scheduling [here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/scheduling).